# Best way to use JWT token in Rest API in Codeigniter. What should be the table schema for Login and Sign up? If I am storing token in table

Tags: php, rest, jwt, codeigniter-3

For the first time I'm making Rest API with token Authorization. Building Login and Sign Up. How should be the table structure and logic to use token after login. What should be the payload if I'm using JWT Token?
When to create token?

I have referred the below video but then, it does not have answer to my question "How to use it?". It just shows how to implement it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-i2epNuiViw and this link to read
http://developer-city.com/jwt

```
Table schema that I have thought off

Table name - User
email
password(hash)
token



Logic for Token Authorisation
After User Sign Up? store jwt token in database? Of which I am not sure off 
how it works.

Just want to know the flow of how to use it throught the project
```

Comment: Please ask your question with code, images and details.

Comment: @javad I just know to know the logic of how to use token? If I come to know that I can implement that

Comment: hey are able to solve that

Answer (score 0):

No need to store token in database. JWT you can create token of your information with a secret key, also can add token validity (in time). When logged in create token and return it. While using token you can verify it with your secret key. If validity time over or token not using your secret key it will provide you exception/ error.